# Creating a Responsive Toggle Button for a <Div>

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, toggle

I am trying to make a responsive filter widget for my website.

1. The **#filter-widget** shows when screen size is larger than 767px, and it hides when screen size is smaller than 767px( .col-sm-3 ).
2. The **Show Fileter** button shows when the screen size is smaller then 767px. Once Users click on this button, **#filter-widget** shows again.

My expected result is like:

Screen size larger than 767px:
[image]

Screen size smaller than 767px:
[image]

My Code is as below:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Eat Your Food</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
      <a href="#filter-widget" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="collapse">Show Filter v</a>
    </div>
    
    <div id="filter" class="col-sm-3">
      <div id="filter-widget" class="collapse in">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
          <h3><b>Category</b></h3>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" value="vegetable" />Vegetable</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" value="meat" />Meat</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" value="grains" />Grains</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Result -->
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <h3>Filted Result Is Here.</h3>
        <p>ResultResultResultResultResult</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to make **#filter-widget** hidden as default when in small screen so I change `<div id="filter" class="col-sm-3">` to be `<div id="filter" class="col-sm-3 hidden-xs">`. However, the **Show Filter** button doesn't work to show **#filter-widget**.

How can I modify my codes to let **Show Filter** hide/show **#filter-widget** when the screen is smaller than 767px.

Is there any problem in my codes ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working sample for you.please remove the `hidden-` classes from your code

**1, CSS**

```
 #filter-widget{display:block}
 .show-filter-button-class{display:none}

 @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
   #filter-widget{display:none}
   .show-filter-button-class{display:block}

 }
```

**2, JS**

```
<script>
$('body).on('click','.show-filter-button-class',function{
 $('#filter-widget').show();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But is there any way that I could just use bootstrap and css without coding JS ?

Comment: @EdChen, you want a `click function` to execute then you have use js or jQuery. no other way that I know of, we can't use CSS for click function. but if you want CSS only then use a `checkbox or radio button` as the button and we can style the div according to if it's `checked or not`